# Unable to Upload (analyzer and code fix extension) to Nuget

Tags: nuget-package, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to upload the analyzer and code fix extension to Visual Studio gallery
It's throwing an error. I have chosen the visual Studio code of extension type of the three available options which I attached in the image. Am I using the correct extension type? or i am doing something wrong.
How to upload the extension to NuGet?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the exception:

> ID must be less than 63 characters and can only contain letters, numbers and dashes.

Your ID contains a `.` - which is not allowed.  It looks like your appending `..{Guid}` to the end of your ID.

Change the ID of your extension to just be `BasicAnalyzer` and you should be fine.  Although, a more specific name might help anyone trying to find and use your analyzer.